# Read JSON using Jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have created a JS file with the following contents;

```
{ "Root":{"APPLICATION":"TestMenu",
          "SUBROOT":["ADMIN","Seller","Buyer"]
       "TAB":"ADMIN":"Home","ADMIN":"LiveAuction","ADMIN":"Master","ADMIN":"PostAuction"]
                  "SUBTAB":[
                            {"APPLICATION":"TestMenu","SUBROOT":"ADMIN","TAB":"HOME","CHILD":"HOME","URL":"\Default.aspx"},
                                {"APPLICATION":"TestMenu","SUBROOT":"ADMIN","TAB":"LiveAuction","CHILD":"","URL":"#"},
                                {"APPLICATION":"TestMenu","SUBROOT":"ADMIN","TAB":"LiveAuction","CHILD":"AuctionCatalog","URL":"\AuctionCatalog.aspx"},
                                {"APPLICATION":"TestMenu","SUBROOT":"ADMIN","TAB":"LiveAuction","CHILD":"BidBook","URL":"\BidBook.aspx"},
                                {"APPLICATION":"TestMenu","SUBROOT":"ADMIN","TAB":"LiveAuction","CHILD":"SampleRequest","URL":"\SampleRequest.aspx"}
                           ]
           }
  }
```

I am calling that JS file with the following code;

```
  $.getJSON("js/TestMenu.js", {}, function (json) { JsonCallBack(json); });
    function JsonCallBack(json) {
        $.each(json.results, function (i, tweet) {
            alert("JSON Data: " + json.Root);
        });
    }
```

Now I want that JSON in single object which I can retrieve but I am not getting that JSON.

When I run firebug I can see that reponse is same. Can anyone tell me why this isn't working?

Comment: I tried to validate your JSON through jsonLint but it seems it's not a valid JSON (http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: use try/catch in your JsonCallBack() to see what's the problem.

Comment: Or you could try using `$.get()` and then `JSON.parse()` on your response. This will tell you if there are errors with your JSON.

Comment: Check `http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/` if yo JSON is fine.

Comment: okies i got it..tnks @Fabrizio Calderan.Now am getting  that json

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is invalid. Use [JSLint](http://jslint.com/) to check if your JSON is valid. JSLint says this:
Error:
Problem at line 1 character 74: Expected '}' to match '{' from line 1 and instead saw 'TAB'.

```
{ "Root":{"APPLICATION":"TestMenu", "SUBROOT":["ADMIN","Seller","Buyer"] "TAB...
```

Problem at line 1 character 79: Expected '}' to match '{' from line 1 and instead saw ':'.

```
{ "Root":{"APPLICATION":"TestMenu", "SUBROOT":["ADMIN","Seller","Buyer"] "TAB...
```

Problem at line 1 character 80: Expected '(end)' and instead saw 'ADMIN'.

```
{ "Root":{"APPLICATION":"TestMenu", "SUBROOT":["ADMIN","Seller","Buyer"] "TAB...
```

JSON: bad.

Comment: Use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) instead. Valid JavaScript is not always valid JSON.